# What caching strategy do you use for a Database dependant ASP.NET App?

Tags: asp.net, database, caching

I'm looking for a good caching strategy for an CRM App written in ASP.NET. Almost all sites depend heavily on the database, which means caching parts/the whole page for some time does not work in my situation. Is there any other way you use caching in these situations?

UPDATE 1:
The setup is the following:
- ASP.NET App hosted on IIS
- App uses either Entity Framework or nHibernate as OR Mapper as Data Access technology - which ever technology has more advantages for my specific requirements
- SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

We use caching for reference data that populates combo boxes and other fields(e.g. help fields) and any values that are unlikely to change frequently.

There are different levels of caching that are stored for different periods of time, including:
Session (lifetime of the session)
Application (lifetime of the web service)

Answer (score 1):

What database engine?

For SQL Server, have you looked at [SqlCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx)? Allows you to retain data sets and provides a cache invalidation mechanism based on notifications from the server. See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for an explanation how it works.

Comment: As far as I know SqlCacheDependency does not work with the Entity Framework.