# ASP.Net Caching

Tags: asp.net, caching

How can we do Database driven caching in ASP.Net.

Comment: What does 'database driven caching' mean? You want to cache items that are normally fetched from the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7312551/2291

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1286456/2291

Answer (score 2):

Oh it is really easy.  You need to Use de Cache object in ASP.NET.  It is different from the Session object since th information stored in the Cache object is global and not per session.  You can activate de Cache per Page or per Web control.  I prefer per Web Control since you have a finer control over what data is cached.

If you need Database driven caching just store your business objects in the Cache object and include logic in your page in case it expires.

example

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e){
  BusinessObject bo = Cache["SomeBO"] as BusinessObject;
  if (bo == null){
    //reload bo from database since data expired...
  }

}
```

check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00323290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SqlDependency` or `SqlCacheDependency` objects.