# how do i achive asp.net data dependancy caching?

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, caching

I have asp.net web applications as well as console apps that run on a schedule. both types have a lot of functionality that is data driven and it would be great to cache the items.

but i need the apps to have access to real time SQL table data, so the cache should be refreshed when ever the SQL table data is changed.

i think i recall some talks about a new data dependency cache advertised in .net 3.5 or .net 4.0 but cant find anything on it now that i need it.

does this functionality exist out of the box with .net (what version)

if not how can i implement something like this. i would hope there is boiler plate code i can reuse since this is somethign millions of apps can benefit from.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2054415/2291

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-sql-cache-dependencies-cs

Comment: Has anyone been successful using this?  I tried it when it came out and was underwhelmed with how it worked.  My DBA less so since IIRC, it put a bunch more strain on the SQL Server.

Comment: I use it all the time when caching items need to be up to date, of course if the table is very volatile I will recommend not caching it at all

Comment: Perhaps that's why we had issues.  I don't remember anymore what that outcome of the testing was (maybe it was the version of SQL we were using didn't work well with this technology).

Comment: FYI: This article describes the older polling method. The push notification feature of SQL Server 2005+ is briefly mentioned but not shown.