# What is the best way to cache a dataset with memory like performance, and having it tied to database changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching

Have anyone came across a opensource project or library in .Net to act as a caching layer between database and the aplication that automaticaly or on request sincronizes the data, so that performance could be improved.

The .Net stack as some festures that can be used, like SqlDependencies and the Cache, but both have problems.

*Tested alternatives:*

- SqlDependency are table based, so when one record on table is updated the whole table is invalidated.
- The Cache object works well but lack the object management features to manage the changes in objects.
- DataTable's in Cache may be a solution, but i would like to deal with the cache as objects not DataRow's.

Any sugestions on system specialized in this task? Any good ORM that can do that?

Comment: have also a look at NHibernate caching...

Comment: Have you checked [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached)?

Comment: Is NHibernate a easy solution to switch to or only suitable when building from scratch? I've used Hibernate with Java and it is great but when u build upon it, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: Memcached seems fine and now have .Net clients, i'll give it a look. But it doesn't solve the sincronization between the database and the cache or does it? You have to do it manualy , right?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849). One of its components is Velocity (which was a research in-memory distributed cache). It's only supported on server editions of Windows.

Comment: Didn't know that, but it seems a good alternative. I'll take a look at the samples to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

`OuputCaching` is a very good way to optimize an application. Even just caching a page for 30sec makes a massive difference to an application under heavily load. `VaryByCustom` allows a great deal of control over how data is cached, as does the .NET output caching engine.

If seeing real-time changes isn't critical, I'd suggest this as a possible alternative to keeping your data in memory, and even then I'd consider optimising specific pieces of data or objects. Keeping DataSets in memory doesn't scale - but of course it depends on your requirements. If you only have a small `DataSet` and can cache it in the `Application cache` then that's not such as bad idea.

Comment: The idea is to have some small and specific and largely used DataSets available for fast access, not the whole database. Now in doing that with `Cache`, but wondering if there is any better solution out there.

Comment: What are the DataSets used for, displaying content? Can you Cache higher up? This is what I'm getting at with output caching, just cache the page not the data if you can.

Comment: Pages are dynamic, but there are some DataSets that are not big and updated not that frequently, as an example the menus data structure, data categories and thing like that, that you don't need to fetch always from DB, but need to be updated when change happens. I know the OutputCaching see it as a layer to be activated later in some pages, for now i want to deal with the data eficiently.

Comment: OK that makes sense. To implement data access layers I would personally implement a decorator around your service layers to cache responses (post any processing/filtering). However it sounds like `DataSet` in the application cache could also work for you. More complex scenarios which can be a configuration nightmare (IMO) have already been mentioned - nHibernate etc do the job well.